# Notification display length in loki

Tags: release-loki, notifications

is there a way to change the display length of notifications in loki? I would like to see the notifications for a little longer.

Thanks for your help

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

There are not any settings to increase the length that notifications stay on the screen. If you miss a notification, you can always review it in the notification indicator