# Change notification appearance timer

Tags: notifications

My question is 2 fold.

How do I change the amount of time that notifications remain visible, i.e once they pop up in the top right, I want them to stay there longer before disappearing.

Also, can this be done at the application level. I.e Can I tweak appearance time for each application individually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this is currently not possible, but see the tip in the provided answer

Answer (score 1):

The last answer I found from the founder on this question was no. See https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9571/14430

I too would love this. They disappear much too fast.