# Any way to configure notification duration?

Tags: notifications

I'm using Slack on elementaryOS and would like its notifications to stay on-screen for a longer duration so that I can read messages without switching focus to the app. Is there any way I can do this? I've looked in the Notification settings window and the dconf editor but couldn't find any relevant settings.

Comment: The notification duration length apparently hasn't yet been implemented in elementary OS 5 (Juno). If you like, you can suggest to implement this feature on elementary/notifications github page (https://github.com/elementary/notifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Daniel's answer for a similar question in Loki may still be relevant to this in Juno. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9571/9220